# Xcode formatting of objective C code

Tags: xcode, eclipse, formatting

I am use to using a feature in eclipse that formats all of my code in a file to the same syntax position by hitting Shift + Ctrl + F. I don't even know what this feature is called but I was wondering if you can do something similar in Xcode for objective-c programming. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit Command + A then Control + I. simple.